# Microsoft Bot Framework how to enable typed/text answer in response to Adaptive Cards

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

What I want to achieve: User is able to type "yes" in the text box, which will trigger a corresponding Adaptive Card button option 'Yes', which will be the same as clicking on the 'Yes' action on the Adaptive Card itself.

What I have tried: I have tried capturing the textResponse within the Method(Waterfall step dialog) I am in, and handling it in that same step, but I have been unsuccessful.

**Example** of code attempted in order to capture textResponse:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptForGuestFirstNameAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity;
    var textResponse = activity.Text?.Trim();

    if (textResponse == "yes")
    {
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(DialogIds.GatherGuestInviteInformation, new 
    PromptOptions {Prompt = prompt}, cancellationToken);
    }

await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(_templateManager.GenerateActivityForLocale("InviteGuestFailedMessage"), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

Why am I not able to get this to work?

Comment: I'm a little lost. It looks like you are trying to prompt the user and check that response (`textResponse == "yes") all in the same step. Is that what you are doing? If so, that is not possible. It must be two steps - one step prompting the user which captures their response, followed by a second step that checks the value of that response and acts accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was trying to achieve (thanks for confirming that it's not possible). If that is not possible, what is the way for the Adaptive Card to recognize a text response by the user "yes" and making that trigger an Action.Submit of a button titled "Yes"? The Adaptive Card is displayed in the previous Async Method (Lets call it method 1), I want method 2 to handle a textResponse from the user to trigger an Adaptive Card button (instead of a mouse click).

Comment: Hi @LockItIn. Welcome to SO. I don't think it is possible to trigger the submit action of the adaptive card via a text-message sent by the user. Why exactly would you like to implement this?

Comment: @Hessel The client has commented that they want this implemented, as they think some staff would naturally assume this is possible. Is there any work around at all? I'm pretty surprised this isn't possible.